# dotvvm: Auto play video list (presentation)

Tags: dotvvm

I like to build a Video presentation website with dotvvm.
when nothing happens it has to start every time a new video from a list.
with the bootstrap/MediaObject i can't find the event 'video ready playing' so we can start the next video.
what is the best way to solve this with Dotvvm, i don't want to go back to angular for this.

Bas

UPDATE: 
At this moment I use the html5  tags, is there also a dotvvm component ? 
sample:

```
    <dot:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentTemplate">
<div class="page">
    <video ID="video1" width="320" height="240" autoplay>
        <source src="/Style/video/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
</div>
<script>
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
    function playPause() {
        if (myVideo.paused)
            myVideo.play();
        else
            myVideo.pause();
    }
   myVideo.addEventListener("ended", function () {
        //get next video from viewmodel, (not hard coded)
        var nextVideo = "/Style/video/video2.mp4"
        myVideo.setAttribute("src", nextVideo)
        //load 
        myVideo.load();
        // switch of sound
        myVideo.muted = true;
        // play
        myVideo.play();
    }, true);
</script>
```

can we get the nextVideo from the viewModel  and how do we do this ?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a little bit? 
Maybe a piece of code of the MediaObject. 
Are you using the commerical Bootstrap for DotVVM controls, or a pure Bootstrap library?

Answer (score 0):

**1) Set javascript variable**

you can set this way - eg. by button with command

MyView.dothtml

```
...
<dot:button Click="{command: SetNextVideo()}" Text="Set next video" />
...
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
....
IDotvvmRequestContext _requestContext;
...

public void SetNextVideo()
{
  //_requestContext.ResourceManager.AddStartupScript("alert('my javascript after command');");
  _requestContext.ResourceManager.AddStartupScript("nextVideo = ...... ");
}
```

**2. Get current value of Viewmodel property in View**

or you can declare declare string property in viewmodel and in your javascript you can get current value by knockout call like this:

Viewmodel

```
public string MyFoo {get;set;} = "bar";
```

View:

```
<script>
....
alert( ko.toJS(dotvvm.viewModels.root.viewModel.MyFoo) );

</script>
```

It depends on your script what you realy want to do :)